# How to authenticate in Gmail AddOn

Tags: authentication, gmail-addons

We are looking at building a gmail add-on for our application. Our application uses custom authentication (different from gmail or google Oauth).

There are few questions:

1. Is it possible to launch a single page application(eg. angularJS application) in gmail add-on?
2. What is the recommended way of authentication and authorization?
3. Is it possible to render or redirect to/from a secure html or jsp page in a gmail add-on?
4. How can we implement authentication flow to get tokens from application which use custom authentication eg. form based authentication?